# how to check that any form field data is changed or not?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

i am working on a asp.net web app in this application when customer logged in then his/her

personal details displayed in form fields (e.g. full name in name box ,age in age box etc) for getting data first i fetch the data from ms sql then assign them to **ICustomer** interface properties this interface is implemented by customer class.

And we also have a update button on customer information page so if without changing any information if a user click on update then unnecessary it will go to server and come back and the same data updated in database,so what i am trying to do is to just detect whether something changed in customer form then only update functionality should work.

i have two option

1. just use Java script and detected the text change then unable update button.
2. make a  temporary reference of ICustomer and compare it to the older when then process by making something true or false.

so please suggest me the best approach for it or any other method.

if question is unclear then just comment on it i will explain more.

Comment: You can write JavaScript code that make note on changes and pass this information when you submit a form.

Comment: Anyone have an answer to this question without javascript? I am having the same issue and .OldValues is always null in the ItemUpdating method. I cannot compare oldvalues with newvalues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript may help you, but it's very unreliable. I say go with the second option. Store the `ICustomer` object in a Session variable and compare it with the new one.

Comment: thanks this one is also one of the correct way if object is small

Answer (score 5):

If you're using the formview or detailsview control in your asp.net webpage, then you can use the [OldValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.itemupdating.aspx) property of the forms's itemupdating event to compare the values before posting to your database.  I believe the form's viewstate must be enabled for this to work.

```
protected void myFormView_ItemUpdating(object sender, FormViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        // Access the old values
        e.OldValues...
```

Here's a full example using the [detailsview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsviewupdateeventargs.oldvalues.aspx).

Comment: thanks for the answer but i am not using formview or details view i am just using a simple form then please suggest me any solution other wise i have to go with object comparsion

Comment: @Peeyush: The simplest solution would be to capture the form values when the page has loaded in javascript and check them when the form's submit button has been clicked.  It would probably be a good idea to cache the values in a session variable and check those at the server, too.  Honestly though, it seems like it would be a better idea to just let the form work as intended and let it update the database.  The small amount of processing that you're saving is not worth having to maintain whatever system you come up with for checking the values.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `TextBox` controls, one option is to use the `TextChanged` event to detect changes.

Answer (score 1):

You should go to 2nd option if the size of your object is not very large as you have to store the old object before comparing to the new object of Icustomer to detect any changes. Otherwise use javascript to detect the changes on the text fields. but as you know its not very much reliable.

Answer (score 0):

the main problem with the Javascript option is that what if user changes value and again change to it's previous state in that case also it'll shows value changed.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31250128)